# time data '06/04/2020, 12:36 pm - ' does not match format '%d/%m/%y, %H:%M %p - ' (match)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

```
df['message_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['message_date'], format = '%d/%m/%y, %H:%M %p - ')
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: time data '06/04/2020, 12:36 pm - ' does not match format '%d/%m/%y, %H:%M %p - ' (match)
```

Comment: [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes): `%y - Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.`. You want `%Y - Year with century as a decimal number.` Voting to close as non-repr / typo.

Answer (score 0):

Change small `%y` to `%Y`

```py
df['message_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['message_date'], format = '%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M %p -')
```